# Ruby - each starting offset

Tags: ruby

How do I set a starting offset for `each` loop in ruby? 
I want the loop to begin from `a[3]` instead of `a[0]`. How do I set that?

```
a = [ab, cd, ef, gh, hi, jk]

a.each do |i|
#some stuff
end
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Another, possibly more direct and readable possibility is to use [`Array#drop`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/drop):

```
a.drop(3).each do |i|
  # do something with item i
end
```

Now this really shines if combined with other methods inherited from [`Enumerable`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable), so chances are there's a better alternative to your imperative `each` loop. Say you want to filter the extracted slice and transform it afterwards:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a.drop(3).select(&:even?).map { |x| x * 2 }
# => [8, 12]
```

Or say you want to print a list of all the values:

```
a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
puts a.drop(3).join("\n")
```

Output:

```
4
5
```

These features inherited from functional programming are what makes Ruby so strong :)

Comment: Which functional programming languages influenced this style of programming?

Comment: @Vass In LISP and later Haskell that heavily rely on persistent singly linked lists this style is pretty common (e.g. you'll find there the classical functions `map`, `filter`, `take`, `drop`, `zip` etc. that you also find in Ruby's `Enumerable` module)

Comment: It would be nice to see a variety of these methods like drop, while implementing binary search or some other sorting algorithm

Comment: @Donato I'm not at all sure what you mean

Answer (score 23):

Use `each` on a [subpart](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) of the array. In the example below, from the fourth element to the end:

```
a[3..-1].each do |i|
  #some stuff
end
```

Comment: a[a.size - 1].each do |i|

Answer (score 4):

This will help you

```
a[3..-1].each do |i|
  #your logic
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Most Rubyist's forget about the good old for loop:

```
n = 3
for i in n...a.size
  puts a[i]
end
```

Comment: Because it sucks, as it doesn't introduce a new scope, which is counter-intuitive as it uses `do/end`. Also, OP wanted to enumerate the array items, not the indices.

Comment: Huh? Each also uses do/end? If you want a new scope, don't use proc closure, use a method call inside the loop. If there is a principial difference between for and each as to their code block, I'd like to know it (I underuse for loops, too :)

Comment: Thanks again, this is what happens if you type quickly. Please correct my answer. But I'd really like to know what do you mean by not introducing a new scope? How does one feel the difference?

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I'have asked this in the main question space already.

Comment: +1 because blocks can slow down your code, and because of the rudeness against the poster.

Answer (score 2):

## Benchmark

For those who interested in benchmark comparison of these methods :)

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

a = Array.new(1000) { |i| i } 
drop_point = 500

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('drop(x)') do
    a.drop(drop_point).each { |el| el + 1 }
  end

  x.report('[x...-1]') do 
    a[drop_point..-1].each { |el| el + 1 }
  end

  x.report('for in') do
    n = drop_point
    size = a.size
    for i in n...size
      a[i] + 1
    end
  end

  x.report('while') do
    size = a.size
    i = drop_point
    while i < size
      a[i] + 1
      i += 1
    end
  end

  x.compare!
end
```

---

#### Results

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
             drop(x)     4.142k i/100ms
            [x...-1]     4.125k i/100ms
              for in     3.239k i/100ms
               while     5.391k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
             drop(x)     42.485k (± 2.3%) i/s -    215.384k in   5.072524s
            [x...-1]     42.533k (± 2.3%) i/s -    214.500k in   5.045832s
              for in     32.855k (± 2.5%) i/s -    165.189k in   5.030958s
               while     53.489k (± 4.5%) i/s -    269.550k in   5.049793s

Comparison:
               while:    53489.3 i/s
            [x...-1]:    42532.8 i/s - 1.26x  slower
             drop(x):    42484.7 i/s - 1.26x  slower
              for in:    32855.4 i/s - 1.63x  slower
```

#### Conclusions

As expected good old `while` is the fastest one as it does not have `block` allocation, but I would prefer either `[x...-1]` or `drop(x)` as they are more readable