# Permutations with a starting index

Tags: ruby, permutation

I am generating a fairly large set of permutations of an array for my algorithm:

```
argeArray.permutation(permSize) do |perm|
  # Do something with perm
end
```

Now I am working to update the application to be able to continue at the index where it got stopped.

After a bit of looking around I did not find an alternative method of `permutation` that has a starting index (to be able to skip `0..startIndex`).

Next I found the [`drop()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396206/ruby-each-starting-offset) which is able cut-off the first number of elements from the permutation enumerator:

```
startIndex = 3000000000 # skip first 3 billion combinations
argeArray.permutation(permSize).drop(startIndex) do |perm|
  # Do something with perm
end
```

But experimentation showed that this creates the *complete* set of combinations, which is not very efficient as it requires *lots* and **lots** of memory... Even when it just needs to skip the first 3 billion combinations...

Another solution is to skip the algorithm until `startIndex` is reached:

```
startIndex = 3000000000 # skip first 3 billion combinations
argeArray.permutation(permSize).with_index() do |perm, index|
  next if index < startIndex # Skip until startIndex is reached
  # Do something with perm
end
```

Disadvantage is that there are 3 billion combinations tested before the algorithm (finally) starts working (and wastefully keeps checking whether `startIndex` is reached)

Are there any other (more efficient) solutions for this problem? To be somehow able to tell `permutation()` to skip an initial amount of combinations? (assuming it always uses the same order)

Comment: I think the only solution is to write your own implementation of `permutation` with an starting index as argument, the one in the core won't help you.

Comment: @tokland Unfortunately that is what I concluded, but I hoped I missed something...

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.0 introduced [`Enumerator::Lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html). Maybe looking into that may help you.

```
module Enumerable
  def filter_map(&block)
    map(&block).compact
  end
end

class Enumerator::Lazy
  def filter_map
    Lazy.new(self) do |yielder, *values|
      result = yield *values
      yielder << result if result
    end
  end
end

(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.filter_map{|i| i*i if i.even?}.first(5)
    # => [4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

You can probably create your permutation as an instance of `Enumerator::Lazy` and use `drop` to skip to a certain position.

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, thanks! Unfortunately, Ruby 2.0 is not yet available (i.e. packaged) for Ubuntu... :( I'll wait a bit until I am going to fiddle to install it manually...

Comment: I use Ubuntu with Ruby 2.0.

Comment: You manually installed it, or used a pre-build package? (I could not find one)

Comment: @sawa, I thought lazy enumerators were not indexable so a `drop` won't be much help, can you expand?

Comment: @Veger I downloaded directly from the Ruby cite, and did `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`.

Comment: @tokland Even if the enumerator itself is not indexable, by keeping track of the length of the result gotten so far or keeping track of the iterations done so far, it is possible to `drop` that amount from the enumerator, I think.

Comment: @sawa So if I understand correctly, with the lazy enumerator all permutations still are generated? Instead of skipping (the permutation algorithm) to the startIndex... It is easy created using a regular iterator loop with something like `next if index < startIndex` (which was my best attempt so far, but still slow)

Comment: @sawa: Well, yes, you can drop elements, but you'll have to calculate them first. The idea was to do this efficiently from a given index. I don't see how to do it without implementing a custom permutation method that has this new argument.